# Boolean vs. Enum for typing "New or Used"

Tags: c#, enums, naming-conventions, boolean

I have a perhaps silly question... I am trying to determine what is the best approach for typing a property whose value will be either "New" or "Used". Do I use an `enum` or should I just go with a `boolean` (e.g. IsNew)? If I go with `enum`, what should I call this type and property name? (public NewOrUsed NewOrUsed {get; set;} <-- confusing)

Obviously, with `enum` I can have state that declares neither value (NONE, NEW, USED) and `enum` is more future-proof (although one can claim there is no chance other values will exist). Again, what is the appropriate name for such a type and property?

With `boolean` - it's pretty straight forward (either using IsNew or IsUsed)

I know it's silly, but I am curious what others think

Regards
Z..

### Update

If you prefer `enum`, please comment on what should be appropriate name for type and property (e.g `public NewUsedType NewOrUsed {get; set;}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment "I allready [sic] have a Condition - it refers to a condition when something is Y"Used" (e.g. used vehicle/book can be in "fair", "like new", "mint" condition) ;)"

So with that piece of information, I'd definitely go with a `bool`.  You already have an extensible way of establishing the condition so this is more of a categorical thing.  You may some time in the future you may want something whether more than one condition counts as "New" say:

```
public enum ConditionType {Fair, LikeNew, Mint, New}

public ConditionType Condition { get; set; }

public bool IsNew
{
    get { return Condition == ConditionType.New || Condition == ConditionType.Mint; }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the way to go since he already has other conditions.

Answer (score 6):

> `enum` is more future proof

Not really. You have no idea what the future will bring. If you need to change it later, then change it. So, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Go with:

```
 public bool IsNew { get; set; }
```

Boom, done. Move on, add value elsewhere.

Comment: I don't like the duplicated property. This suggests some kind of independence. And once you add a third state the setters will break anyways.

Comment: I would prefer this solution, definitely. It declares public interface which is clear and good (IsNew, IsUsed), and you can freely change the implementation behind in the future (in the case you would need some addtions or changes).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this code simpler than an `enum`. I also don't like having *two* properties, even though the object could only ever be in *one* of the states ("new" or "used") at any given time. It could be a good source of confusion.

Comment: @Jason So what if the future does bring another choice...I'd have to do another IsXXX and have if/then/else logic in the setter...Not really clean...

Comment: @zam6ak: And what if the future doesn't bring another choice? Stop worrying about it. Move on!

Comment: @Jason Boom move on, add value elsewhere, year later future "happens" and you end up spending hours/days refactoring and recoding...Where is your value then? My question was not weather or not future will happen but rather what approach would be least disruptive and adaptable to change?

Comment: @zam6ak: I think in this case, the `enum` is more adaptable to future changes.

Comment: @zam6ak: Hours/days for refactoring after this decision? Please. Also, I have no idea how much time you've already spent thinking about it, but you've already lost at least twenty-four minutes on it. Additionally, you do not know that making it an `enum` or whatever is going to save you this "hours/days" in the future. You don't know what the future will bring in this case.

Comment: @zam I don't think the work needed to refactor from boolean to enum is that much bigger than the refactoring needed to handle an additional enum value.

Comment: Also, for those saying an `enum`, note that most `enum` guidelines advise against using an `enum` when the `enum` value set could change ("Do not use an enum for open sets (such as the operating system version.") Here, you are choosing an `enum` exactly to protect yourself against a change in the value set, this violating one of the guidelines of using an `enum`.

Comment: @Jason I agree that I don't know what future will bring, but neither do you. So if 25 minutes of considering this saves me time later, I am all for it...But back to my point - what approach (in your opinion) would be least disruptive and adaptable to change?

Comment: @zam6ak: I don't know. We don't have all the information. What I do know is that right now you need a way to detect if something is new or not. I know that an auto-property of type `bool` named `IsNew` satisfies the requirement. I know that is the simplest thing that satisfies the requirement. You haven't given us any additional constraints on this property. Therefore, I would go with `public bool IsNew { get; set; }` absent additional information.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I would respectfully disagree just based on my previous experience having to fix bunch of view models from using 2 booleans to using single multi value enum (PITA) :)...

Answer (score 4):

Use an enum. I would call it `Condition`. You don't need a `None` value. You can just make it nullable.

Comment: If you already use an enum, then adding a None value is probably nicer than using a nullable. Nullables are pretty annoying to work with in my experience.

Comment: I allready have a Condition - it refers to a condition when something is "Used" (e.g. used vehicle/book can be in "fair", "like new", "mint" condition) ;)

Comment: I'd then add a value `new` to that condition enum.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the enum, if I found myself constantly translating the boolean value into the value "new" or "used".

If I were more interested in this value as an indicator (such as doing `if(something.isNew)`), I'd use a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

For New I would use a boolean, an enum in this case would be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

eBay has New, and New Other, to distinguish between merchandise sold in its original packaging and merchandise  sold in different packaging or no packaging.  I'd go for the enum for its extensibility, what you called "future proof".

Answer (score 1):

I'm generally opposed to over-engineering, so my first instinct was using a boolean.

But conceptually it doesn't feel like a logical boolean value. It feels like an enumeration which happens to have two values at the moment. I typically think about the conditions as `new` and `used` and not as `new` and `not new` in my head.

I expect other `Condition`s being added at a later point in time, such as `refurbished`. But of course refactoring from a single property won't be that hard thanks to IDE features like `Find All References`. And you'll need to retouch the logic using this property anyways once you add new values to the enumeration.

Future-proofing is the less important reason for me. That it doesn't feel conceptually clean is more important IMO.

Comment: refactoring a property name is not an issue at all...But changing the code from using boolean instead of enum (or vice versa) is more involved, I would think...Good insight though...

Comment: Refactoring the property name isn't the problem. But once you add another value to the enum you need to retouch all the places where the property is used to handle the additional potential values.